# Is there a way I can convert mpz_t to int or unsigned long int in C++?

Tags: c++, gmp

I have data in `mpz_t` and I want to assign that data to `int` or `unsigned long int`. The data/numbers are small in `mpz_t` and can be stored into in back. Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to `mpz_t` from [gmp(gnu multi-precision)](https://gmplib.org/) library, you can do the conversion using:

```
unsigned long int mpz_get_ui (const mpz_t op)
```

Reference: https://gmplib.org/manual/Converting-Integers